# How do I prevent $html-link() from removing the single quotes when adding an 'onmouseover' event in CakePHP?

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp

Trying to use an onmouseover event

```
echo $html->link("Dashboard", 
     "/dashboard/index", 
     array("onmouseover" => "Tip('Test');") );
```

becomes

```
<a href="/dashboard/index" onmouseover="Tip(&#039;Test&#039;);">Dashboard</a>
```

How do I prevent the link function from removing the single quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Cake 1.2, this should definitely work:

```
echo $html->link('Dashboard', '/dashboard/index',
array("onmouseover" => "Tip('Test');"), null, false);
```

The last parameter is the escape option. It defaults to true.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
echo $html->link("Dashboard", 
     "/dashboard/index", 
     array("onmouseover" => "Tip('Test');"),
     array('escape' => false));
```

Comment: added onclick="return confirm(&#039;Array&#039;);"  after the onmouseover. It went into the confirm return true/false parameter of link.