# How do I implement JavaScript onmouseover in CakePHP?

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, dom-events, cakephp-2.1

What I want to do is convert the following to work with CakePHP:

```
<a href="URL ADDRESS"><img src="URL OF THE FIRST IMAGE GOES HERE" onmouseover="this.src='URL OF THE SECOND IMAGE GOES HERE'" onmouseout="this.src='URL OF THE FIRST IMAGE GOES HERE'" /></a>
```

I have the following so far:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image("animalhealth.png", array(
    "alt" => "Animal Health",
    "onmouseover" => "this.src='animalhealthhover.png'",
    "onmouseout" => "this.src='animalhealth.png'",
    'url' => array('controller' => 'records', 'action' => 'index'
    )
)); ?>
```

The problem are the `onmouseover` & `onmouseout` event lines. I need to tell cake to somehow use the helper method otherwise it just selects no image. I don't want to have to put the entire address in as the is a navigation menu and there will be multiple instances of the app at different locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to build a work around using CSS.

Made a custom image for the button Icon.

This is what goes in the view/layout page:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li>
                        <div id="button_name"><?php
                    echo $this->Html->image("name_of_img.png", array(
                        "alt" => "Animal Health",
                        'url' => array('controller' => 'controllerName', 'action' => 'index')));
                    ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Link Text'), array('controller' => 'controllerName', 'action' => 'index')); ?> 
                        </div>
                    </li> 
</ul>
```

If your not using cakePHP you could do it like this in a normal HTML page:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li>
                        <div id="button_name"><a href="/path/to/page.html"><img src="/path/to/img/imagename.png" alt="Animal Health" /></a><a href="/path/to/page.html">Animal Health</a> 
                        </div>
                    </li>
<ul>
```

This Makes both the text and the icon clickable.

Then the CSS:

```
.menu li {padding:0px; border: 0px; margin: 0px; list-style: none;
          float: left; margin-left: 0px; display: block; height: 36px;} //remove any stlying and set up for the menu.

#button_name{background-color: darkorange;
               float: left;
              margin-right: 5px;
               margin-top: 1px;
               margin-bottom: 0px;
               padding: 1px 3px 1px 3px;
               -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
               border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
               border: 1px black;
               text-align: right;
               color: #6495ED;
               font-weight: bold;
               -webkit-transition: all 1000ms;
               -moz-transition: all 1000ms;
               -o-transition: all 1000ms;
               -ms-transition: all 1000ms;
               transition: all 1000ms;}
#button_name a {
    -webkit-transition: all 1000ms;
    -moz-transition: all 1000ms;
    -o-transition: all 1000ms;
    -ms-transition: all 1000ms;
    transition: all 1000ms;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #6495ED; 
}
    #button_name:hover
 {background-color: #6495ED;}
    #button_name:hover a // VERY IMPORTANT see note
{
        font-weight: bold;
        color: darkorange;}
```

This makes a nice button with 2 rounded top corners. When you hover over the button anywhere the background and text colours transition between each other. ie: text goes from blue to orange and background goes from orange to blue.

Note about #button_name:hover a:
You must set it as specified if you set it as "button_name a:hover" the text will stay the same color as the background.

Hopefully this will help someone else.

Still keen to hear any ideas about doing it with the JS.

Answer (score 0):

This post may help you to resolve your issue.

[How do I prevent $html-link() from removing the single quotes when adding an 'onmouseover' event in CakePHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815721/html-link-using-onmouseover)

Example :

echo $html->link("Dashboard", 
     "/dashboard/index", 
     array("onmouseover" => "Tip('Test');"),
     array('escape' => false));

Comment: Wasn't quite what I needed but appreciate you time just the same, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $html->link($this->Html->image("animalhealth.png", array("alt" => "Animal Health")), array('controller' => 'records', 'action' => 'index'),array("onmouseover" => "Tip('Test');"), null, false);
```

you can specify a link with the image and provide onmouseover with that link

Answer (score 0):

Html->image('edit.png',['url'=> ['action' => 'edit', $playerEventRegistration->id]],array("onmouseover" => "Tip('Test');") ?>